# Построчный вывод данных из динамической таблицы в новую таблицу

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, java-ee

Имеется динамическая таблица. Значения подтягиваются из бд. Подскажите как можно реализовать так, чтобы при клике на строку таблицы выводились данные этой строки на новой странице в отдельной таблице.

```
while (result.next()) {
  out.write("<tr>");
  for (int i=1; i<=columns; i++) {
    out.write("<td>" + result.getString(i) + "</td>");
  }
  out.write("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки умеете выводить?
Например так

```
...
String val = result.getString(i);
String id = i == 1 ? val : id;
String href = request.getContextPath() + pathToRecordServlet + "?id=" + id;
out.write("<td><a href=\"" + href + \">" + val + "</a></td>");
...
```

`pathToRecordServlet` - здесь должен быть путь к сервлету, который покажет страницу со строкой. Например если Ваше приложение называется MyApp, а сервлет будет доступен по адресу http://server/MyApp/RecordServlet, то `pathToRecordServlet` = "/RecordServlet".

`id` - какой-то уникальный идентификатор строки. В примере предполагается, что id в первой колонке.

Таким образом получите в каждой колонке ссылку, щёлкнув по которой перейдёте на страницу с отдельно взятой строкой.

`request.getContextPath()` вернёт `"/MyApp"`, `pathToRecordServlet` = `"/RecordServlet"`, `id` пусть будет `3`. Ссылка должна получится такой
`<a href="/MyApp/RecordServlet?id=3">...</a>`

Сервлет, который отвечает за эту страницу должен посмотреть параметр `id`, извлечь из базы или иным способом получить нужную строку. Ну а дальше нарисуете её как-нибудь.

Чтобы сработало по щелчку в любое место строки, а не только по ссылке, надо скрипт сделать. Он должен определять над какой ячейкой щёлкнули и извлекать из неё ссылку.